# Resource Not Found Using sfdx force:org:create

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox, vs-code, visualstudiocode, dev-hub

I am attempting to use a sandbox of my production org as a DevHub for scratch orgs. In VSCode, I am using the built-in sfdx application to do this, first creating an sfdx project, then authorizing my sandbox

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
```

but when I try to create a default scratch org, I get the following error:

```
08:33:23.746 sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias FirstScratch --durationdays 30 --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal
08:33:25.195 sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias FirstScratch --durationdays 30 --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal
 ended with exit code 1

The requested resource does not exist
```

Other people having this problem seemed to have it because they did not enable DevHub, but my DevHub is a sandbox. Is it possible that I have this error because I didn't enable DevHub in my production org until after I created my sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm&type=5) says:

> NOTE You can’t enable Dev Hub in a sandbox.

You must use a Developer Edition Org or a Production Org for your Dev Hub.